# Facebook API receive Wall posts

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

At the moment I am working with the Facebook API and ASP.Net (MVC4).

Is it possible to post a certain message on my Facebook Wall and receive that message in my web application?

I already tried the next code, but it doesn't work:

Maybe somebody has a solution? (Also I don't want the posts of the news feed, but of my profile wall)

```
JsonObject fbJsonFeedObj = (JsonObject)fbApp.Get(" https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=from,message,name,picture&access_token=" + token);

string str = fbApp.Get("/me/feed").ToString();
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(str);
JToken jUser = obj["data"];
int numb = jUser.Count();

//Get latest post
int id_post = 0;
string stringMsg = obj["data"][id_post]["likes"].ToString();
```

**Update:** 
I just want a method that gets the latest posts of my personal FB wall. How to accomplish this?

**Update 2:**
Today I tried:

> JsonObject fbJsonFeedObj = (JsonObject)fbApp.Get("
>   https://graph.facebook.com/" + FacebookModel.TestFacebookID +
>   "/feed?access_token=" + token);

With this code I can get the latest post, but how do I split it in a readable string? So I only get the UserId who send the post and the real (string) message?

**Update 3:**
At the moment I am using this code to get the wall posts:

```
  var wall = (JsonObject)fbApp.Get("/me/feed");
```

But Visual Studio shows this error:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

I am using the next method to receive the accesstoken:

```
 public static string GetAccessToken()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                client_secret = FACEBOOK_SECRET,
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            });
            return result.access_token;
        }
```

How to solve this problmen?

Comment: Did you got the `obj` correctly?

Comment: The application receives the obj correctly. The problem is that the obj contains the latest news feed, but not the latest post of my Facebook Wall. I just want a method that get the latest posts of my personal FB wall. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial problem is that you were using `/home` and not `/feed`.

`/home` - The user's news feed.
`/feed` - The user's wall.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

You can split it the same way you did with the previous (`/home`) object

```
//Get latest post
int id_post = 0;
string stringPostId = obj["data"][id_post]["id"].ToString(); //Id of the post
string stringPostSender = obj["data"][id_post]["from"]["name"].ToString(); //Name of sender
string stringPostSenderId = obj["data"][id_post]["from"]["id"].ToString(); //ID of sender
```

Each object looks like this so you should be able to figure out how to drill down

```
{
      "id": "5_11111111", 
      "to": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "User A", 
            "id": "4"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "from": {
        "name": "User B", 
        "id": "5"
      }, 
      "message": "This is a test message", 
      "created_time": "2013-10-04T23:01:42+0000"
    }
```

Your last update is a common mistake many first time developers make.

An **application** access token should not be used for these calls. You must have a login flow to grant a **user** access token via OAuth by starting with

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

Please read in detail https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/ for an explanation of the process.

[image: Login Flow]

Comment: Thank you! I have a related question to get the Facebook Wall posts: See Update 3 in first post.

Comment: Is it possible to get the wall posts without logging in? Or can I grant once permission to do this?

Comment: @Odrai you can use a page or app access token (once issued you wouldn't need to login https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token ) for public posts anything else needs a user access token.

Comment: But in the first post (Update 3), I can not check the wall with a App access token? Can I do this with a page access token?

Comment: @Odrai that's because you are using the `/me` endpoint which needs a user access token to identify who "me" is as opposed to qualifying to the actual id or username e.g. graph.facebook.com/zuck/feed

Comment: Mmm ok I understand that. The problem is that I do not want to login. I just want to get all the posts (public and private) of a Facebook. The web application should login automatically or have permission of Facebook to look at his own profile... Is this possible?

Comment: So there is no solution to give an app permission to get all posts of a user wall? (So the user give once the app permission and the app can always access the private and public wall posts)?

Comment: @Odrai All solutions require going through a login flow at least once. See [Getting Your Facebook Page On Your Website With Access Tokens](http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/)